# How to compact views in PouchDB

Tags: pouchdb

CouchDB provides three compaction-related API endpoints:

1. [/{db}/_compact](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/compact.html) to compact data on disk.
2. [/{db}/_compact/{ddoc}](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/compact.html#db-compact-design-doc) to compact a view
3. [/{db}/_view_cleanup](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/compact.html#db-view-cleanup) to clean up stale views.

PouchDB offers similar functionality for the first one.

1. [compact()](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#compaction) to compact on-disk data

But the other two are unclear from the documentation. [viewCleanup()](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#view_cleanup) appears to correspond to `/{db}/_view_cleanup`, with its description reading:

> Cleans up any stale map/reduce indexes.
>
> As design docs are deleted or modified, their associated index files (in CouchDB) or companion databases (in local PouchDBs) continue to take up space on disk. viewCleanup() removes these unnecessary index files.
>
> See [the CouchDB documentation on view cleanup](http://couchdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/maintenance/compaction.html#views-cleanup) for details.

However, the [link](http://couchdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/maintenance/compaction.html#views-cleanup) in the description describes view compaction (and immediately after, discusses view cleanups).

So how does one *actually* compact a view in PouchDB?

- Does `viewCleanup()` handle both view cleanup *and* compaction?
- Is view compaction included in `compact()`?
- Is view compaction impossible?
- Is view compaction somehow simply unnecessary in PouchDB for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [source code in pocuhdb-mapreduce.js](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/blob/77547f7fceb4832648d02bf4a7c7f1c149a33992/packages/node_modules/pouchdb-mapreduce/src/index.js#L772-L824), it looks like viewCleanup just removes unused view locally and also [on remote CouchDB servers](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/blob/77547f7fceb4832648d02bf4a7c7f1c149a33992/packages/node_modules/pouchdb-mapreduce/src/index.js#L765-L770). There is no equivalent of a view compaction, because it's not necessary locally – see [Nolan's answer on Github](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/4118).